# Mongoid strategy for query on associated models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid, nosql

Saying I have this simple application:

```
class LearningGroup
  has_many :students
end

class Student
  belong_to :learning_group
  has_many :grades
end

class Grade
  belong_to :student
end
```

I would like to get all grades in learning group scope.

I could do it in both ways:

```
class Grade
  belong_to :student
  belong_to :learning_group
  before_create :cache_learning_group

  def cache_learning_group
    self.learning_group = grade.learning_group
  end
end
```

and then call `Grade.where(learning_group: LearningGroup.first)`

but I could also do:

```
class Grade
  belong_to :student
  scope :for_learning_group, ->(group) { :student_id.in => group.student_ids }
end
```

which one is more efficient? Which one should I use?

Comment: You'd have to try both approaches and benchmark with real data. Get used to denormalizing your data if you're going to be using MongoDB, you're going to be doing it all the time just to get things to work let alone work quickly.

Comment: I just feel so bad when denormalising data :/ I'm new to the project with ~50 rails models and doing first approach (with caching relation from associated model) makes me really afraid if it breakes something

Comment: Yes, it hurts and it makes my inner DBA weep bitter tears but denormalization (and copy-with-modification) is how things work in MongoDB. You don't have JOINs so you have to implement JOINs yourself by denormalizing or doing it by hand outside the database. You can probably get away with the second "double query" approach if the groups are small.